# Javascript date validation for mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript

Following is the pattern  i used for Java script  `mm/dd/yyyy`. When I compile Script it is showing error.Can some tell why it is showing error.Also Please clarify me if I  want to use special character like `(/,-',',# @ )` in pattern.How to delimit the special character in the pattern?

```
var patt=/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

Comment: This code snippet is valid. The error you are seeing must be from something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` mark modifier to say "either one of the chars before this, or none". In this case you would want to use the `/` So you can use any of these chars, but only 1.

so the pattern would like this to allow any 1 delimiter or not any at all :

`/[0-9]{2}[\/#@-]?[0-9]{2}[\/#@-]?[0-9]{4}$/`

regexp to allow any delimiter but at least 1.

`/[0-9]{2}[\/#@-]{1}[0-9]{2}[\/#@-]{1}[0-9]{4}$/`

Comment: This would allow 26062014 as valid input, which the op probably doesn't want.

Comment: Didn't he say he wants to have the delimiter as an optional char?

Comment: Thanks for you response.But I Need to have mandatory Occurrence '/'.But if use ? It indicates zero or one Occurrence.Can tell me how to delimit a special character in Regular Expression?

Comment: Here try, this regex that I posted.

Comment: then just remove the `?`. i.e.   `^([0-9]{2}[\/#@-]){2}[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Are you saying u want them to be able to use a delimiter?